# multiple rightbar buttons in navigationbar in xcode4.2

Tags: iphone, ios5, uinavigationbar, rightbarbuttonitem

I want to create three buttons in right side of Navigation bar.I am using storyboard for creating the UIView Controller.
In DetailViewController am Embedded a Navigation bar using storyboard and then creating three UIBarButtonItem programetically and then adding these in an array then assigning it to navigationitem.This is working fine.

```
UIBarButtonItem *Button1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Button1" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                           target:self action:@selector(Button1Clicked:)] ;

UIBarButtonItem *Button2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Button2" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                             target:self action:@selector(Button2Clicked:)] ;

UIBarButtonItem *Button3 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Button3" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                              target:self action:@selector(Button3Clicked::)] ;

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems =
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:Button1,Button2,Button3, nil];
```

I have another viewcontroller this is a modalviewcontreoller. I am creating the view controller using storyboard and adding a navigationbar not a navigationcontroller.Then using the same method for adding buttons to navigtion bar, but not shown any buttons.
Plese anyone know how to solve this issue.?

Comment: Please provide some info or code where you stuck exactly

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply.When clicking on a button a new Vewcontroller is displayed i want a navigation bar with three buttons on the rightside of this viewcontroller.The above code not working on this.What am missing?

Answer (score 1):

If your viewController is in `UINavigationController` you can simply use

```
self.navigationItem ...
```

which works fine as I see. But if your viewController (your modal in this case) is **not** in `UINavController`, you have to access `UINavigationItem` in this way:

```
someNavigationBar.topItem ...
```

So, if you set an `IBOutlet` to your navigationBar, your code should look like this one:

```
UIBarButtonItem *Button1 = ...
UIBarButtonItem *Button2 = ...
UIBarButtonItem *Button3 = ...

yourNavigationBar.topItem.rightBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:Button1, Button2, Button3, nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add `UINavigationBar` instead of `UINavigationItem`